# Nginx serving single static file fails when receiving full path

Tags: image, nginx, static, content-type

I've been setting up a very simple naive nginx config block just to server a single image on a path using an alias. Here is the config:

```
location /images/logo/ {
    alias /var/www/logo.png;
}
```

Requesting the server on `hostname/images/logo` gives me the image pushed (not displayed). However, requesting it with trailing / as defined in the location will give me an error. Specifically indexing based on logs:

> [alert] 16367#16367: *3 "/var/www/logo.pngindex.html" is not a directory

Which is frustrating, but ok I added `autoindex off;` to the configuration block. Same error still. I tried to change the location to a regex to make the trailing `/` optional but that also does not seem to do much.

I feel rather beaten by a simple static alias. I simply want the path `/images/logo/` to return the image regardless of a trailing slash. Does anyone know a simple fix for this?

Additionally I assumed adding `default_type image/png;` to the block would fix the content type so NGINX would help the browser display and not download the image but that also does not seem to work.

TLDR:

- Trying to get NGINX to respond with a static image on a path with or without trailing `/`
- Trying to get NGINX to respond with the right content-type for browsers to understand

Answer (score 2):

Rather than an `alias` statement, you could use a `try_files` to define the file name. The advantage being that the file's extension will be declared which will make MIME types work correctly.

For example:

```
location /images/logo {
    root /var/www;
    try_files /logo.png =404; 
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Still fails with trailing slash or not which is my biggest problem. It does serve the file. just the trailing slash stays a problem

Comment: Also, notice that the trailing `/` is removed from the `location` statement so that it matches the URI with or without the trailing `/`. I have tested this solution and it works with **any** URI that begins with `/images/logo`.

Comment: Still getting: `[05/Jan/2020:23:56:17 +0000] "GET /images/logo/ HTTP/1.1" 404 199`

I figured it would match with or without but really doesn't wanna go for it.